# Using Interface, Polymorphism, Abstract for multiple object types into array, Java

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, abstract

Basic assignment:

> A method called draw() will be used for drawing objects, a method
>   called rotate() will be used for rotating objects, a method called
>   resizeObject() will be used for resizing objects, and a playSound()
>   method will be used for playing sounds.
>
> 1. Design the interface classes Drawable, Rotatable, Resizable and Sounds.
> 2. Develop a program called ManipulateAnimals that does the following:    An Animal class will be used to model some basic characteristics of
>      animals for the application.    An animal will have a name attribute
>      and methods to set the name and get the name.    Animals can make
>      sounds and are drawable, rotatable, and resizable.
>
>    A Vehicle class will be used to model some basic characteristics of
>      vehicles. A vehicle will have a name and an age, and methods to
>      get/set these attributes. Vehicles can also make sounds and are
>      drawable, rotatable, and resizable.
>
>    Create a collection of 2 vehicles and 2 animals stored in the same array. Loop through the array and execute the draw(), rotate(),
>      resizeObject(), and playSound() methods polymorphically for each
>      element in the array.

Current Dilemma: I am currently not sure how to implement an abstract class (given the animal and vehicle share draw, rotate, resize, sound). If that is the case, then I think I would be able to make an array of the abstract class type. Iterating through it should be no problem. I just can't seem to work my head around the problem, likely because I've been studying all day :(
Help, Suggestions, Admonishments, Encouragement welcomed!

Current Code:

```
public class Main {

public interface Drawable{
    void draw();
}
public interface Rotatable{
    void rotate();
}
public interface Resizable{
    void resize();
}
public interface Sounds{
    void sounds();
}

public static class Animal implements Drawable, Rotatable, Resizable, Sounds{
    String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing an Animal");
    }

    @Override
    public void rotate() {
        System.out.println("Rotating an Animal");
    }

    @Override
    public void resize() {
        System.out.println("Resizing an Animal");
    }

    @Override
    public void sounds() {
        System.out.println("Animal Sounds");

    }
}
public static class Vehicle implements Drawable, Rotatable, Resizable, Sounds{

    String name;
    int age;

    public Vehicle(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing a Vehicle");
    }

    @Override
    public void rotate() {
        System.out.println("Rotating a Vehicle");
    }

    @Override
    public void resize() {
        System.out.println("Resizing a Vehicle");
    }

    @Override
    public void sounds() {
        System.out.println("Vehicle Sounds");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Animal animal1 = new Animal("Rex");
    Animal animal2 = new Animal("Dharma");
    Vehicle vehicle1 = new Vehicle("Maia", 11);
    Vehicle vehicle2 = new Vehicle("Lilith", 3);

    /*animal1.draw();
    animal1.rotate();
    animal1.resize();
    animal1.sounds();

    what I need to do for all the things*/

   Array things[] = {animal1, animal2, vehicle1, vehicle2};
        for(int i = 0; i < things.length; i++ ){
            things[i].draw();
            things[i].rotate();
            things[i].resize;
            things[i].sounds;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/5743988) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/226788).

Comment: I **do not** expect someone to write my code. I was providing info. I would be more than **ecstatic** to be **nudged** in the right direction. I am in fact paying for my education. It will not likely be turned in on time, again because reasons. But I'm pretty sure these topics will be on the exam. Which I won't be posting on the nets, anywhere. And I promise, I was born before your parents were married.

Comment: No worries. None of those things are reasons why I linked to those articles. Your question just seems to be missing a specific programming question. You've given your assignment description and your current code, but in the process have neglected to ask a question and have been very vague about what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you struggling with abstract class here.

The only issue that could be here is the naming of it. It's not obvious how to name a concept which includes `Drawable, Rotatable, Resizable, Sounds`.

So this is something you should think about.

Here just for illustration lets name the abstraction `AbstractActions`.

So the could with it will look like:

```
abstract class AbstractActions  implements Drawable, Rotatable, Resizable, Sounds{}

class Vehicle extends AbstractActions {
// Skip for brevity
}

class Animal extends AbstractActions {
// Skip for brevity
}
```

And afterwords you can iterate through `AbstractActions`.

Also as a note, if there will be no implementation in your abstract class, you better change it to an interface, which aggregates other interfaces.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I will be trying when I get home tonight! I turned it in incomplete, but must have it working for my own type-A peace of mind!

Comment: @bubblyBibliophile if this answer worked for you feel free to accept it

Comment: abstract class AbstractActions implements D..., R..., R..., S...{}
    class Animal extends AbstractActions {}
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Animal animal1 = new Animal();
       AbstractActions things[] = {animal1};
       for...;
    }
So, I'm having constructing  new AbstractActions or Animals in main. I'm get the "cannot be referenced from static content". Which is kinda like "you're missing a semicolon, but I'm not telling you where and giving you another error to throw you off the scent" Hopefully enough info above to show you current structure.